# Relationship between iterable and Array in Spark

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

I notice that if I apply a `mapPartitions` on an RDD, the partitions get an iterable object. Within the `mapPartitions` function, I then call the `toArray` member function of the iterable to convert that iterable object to an Array object. Does calling `toArray` involves copying, or does it just start referencing the same part of the memory as an Array? If it does involve copying, what are ways to prevent copying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One important correction to your question -- the partition data structure exposed during `mapPartitions` is an Iterator, not Iterable.  Here's the interface difference:

- An `Iterator` has the `next()` and  `hasNext()` methods, which allow you to visit each element in the collection once.  Once the `next()` method of an iterator is called, the last element is gone (unless you've stored it in a variable).
- An `Iterable` has the ability to produce an `Iterator` whenever you want.  This lets you visit each element as many times as you want.

In terms of implementation, an `Iterator` can stream through data.  You really only need to have one element in memory at a time, which is loaded when `next()` is called.  If you're reading from a text file with Spark (`sc.textFile`) it does exactly this, and uses almost no memory to do simple iteration through partitions.

You're absolutely allowed to call `iterator.toArray`, but you probably don't want to.  You end up shoving all of the data into memory (Spark can't load just one element at a time, because you've asked for all of it at once), and either copy each piece of the data (for primitives, like `Int`) or allocate a new reference for each piece of data (for `AnyRef`, like `Array[_]`).  There is no way to prevent this copying.

There are times when converting a partition iterator to an array is what you want to do, but these use cases are rare.  You risk running out of memory and slowing down your application a huge amount due to unnecessary allocation and GC, so think hard about whether it's really needed!

Comment: Then my next question would be, can an Iterator get a certain number of elements, rather than just one element at a time?

Comment: There's nothing prebuilt to do this, but you could certainly write something that `extends Iterator` and can keep track of the last `n` elements.  If you're looking for inspiration, see `iterator.buffered`: this constructs a `BufferedIterator` that lets you peek at the next element without removing it.

Comment: Possibly you want `iterator.grouped(size)`, which will give you an iterator over `Seq`s of the specified size.